# Получить кординаты пользователя Yandex Map Kit for iOS

Tags: ios, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Пишу приложение с использованием Yandex MapKit и не получается получить координаты пользователя. Использую версию 3.0.0. Примеры, которые есть не полны, а документация довольно таки не понятна для меня.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подпишись на YMKUserLocationObjectListener

```
let userLocationLayer = map.userLocationLayer
userLocationLayer.setObjectListenerWith(self)

extension MyMapViewController : YMKUserLocationObjectListener {
    func onObjectAdded(with view : YMKUserLocationView) {
        userLocation = view.pin.geometry
    }
}
```

Comment: Так же все, кто не смог найти ответы на вопросы рекомендую смотреть примеры коды яндекса! Они в версии 3.4.0 изменили пользование userLocationLayer

Answer (score 1):

Отобразить пин пользователя можно через [UserLocationLayer](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/UserLocationActivity.java).
Если просто нужно получить местоположение пользователя, то с этим может помочь [LocationManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationManager-docpage/).

Comment: Спасибо) А можно пример кода, как у вас реализовано просто получение широты и долготы пользователя?